# OEM Vulkan support on Itel A48 (L6006s) unavailable despite Android's and Arm's specification

Tags: hardware, termux, graphics, android-go, gpu

I have Itel A48 (L6006s). I've confirmed that it has a Mali-T820 GPU, which supports OpenGL®ES 1.1, 2.0, 3.1, 3.2, Vulkan 1.0, OpenCL™ 1.1, 1.2 Full Profile, RenderScript™.

[image: Mali-T820 specification on Arm's website.]

However, as I was coding a Vulkan app, putting a call to `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, nullptr)` informs me that no devices are available. `vulkaninfo` on Termux gives "ERROR at vector".

Does Itel A48 (L6006s) support Vulkan?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this device runs on the watered-down version *Android Go* edition, thus some heavy usage features such as graphical computation might be disabled.

Comment: I've tried to find out whether vulkan is not available on the android 10 go edition, found no information, however, the device has an aarch64 capable CPU but is restricted to the armv7-a instruction set, so I guess the vulkan unavailability might simply be another restriction the AOSP or OEM doesn't just think is worth mentioning.